# Android locale support for Indian regional languages(Kannada, Tamil, etc.)

Tags: android, localization

I am able to switch to Hindi locale from my app, i.e, get the appropriate resources for Hindi from values-hi...But when I follow the same for language like Kannada(values-kn) the locale is switched but it displays blank for every text in Kannada. How can I add support for Indian regional languages like Kannada, Tamil, etc.. I want it same as it does for Hindi, i.e, pick the resources from appropriate values-xx folder..I searched through Google and most of them suggest having the fonts(.ttf) file in assets and for every TextView, Button, etc. set it using setTypeFace...but this will be more complicated..as I have locale specific text used every where like in Activity title, Progress dialogs,etc...And even most of the widgets are dynamically created.

My minimum Android SDK target version is 4.0...So I really don't care whether it works or not for Android version<4. I have tested it so far on emulator..So don't know whether it will be same for real devices too..

**Edit :** I have tested the app on Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.2 and it does show text in Kannada, Tamil, Telugu...most of the Indian languages. Have to test for other devices or lower version(v4.0-4.3)

Comment: Hi Xavier, did you find solution to your problem ?

Comment: Use custom font. Download the default Noto fonts for supporting languages and use them. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml